# Is it possible to "share" node.js/express.js routes/code?

Tags: node.js, express

We have a node.js/express.js application (nodeServer.js) that supports a set of routes as follows:

```
// Routes
var xml = require('./routes/xml');
var process = require('./routes/api/process');
.
.
.
// Routes
app.use('/arest/xml', xml);
app.use('/api/process', process);
.
.
```

When the process.js is executed, it first check the req.headers for the content-type, and, if it is application/xml, it performs basically the same processing as the processing that is in the xml.js (it performs different processing if the content-type is application/json).

In other words, the processing (and code) for xml.js is kind of basically replicated.

That code has been in place for awhile now, and now I was asked to make some enhancements to the processing that the xml.js does, and that will mean that I have to make the same changes two places (in both the xml.js and duplicating the same changes also in process.js.

Is there any way to make the processing in the xml.js to just branch off and do the processing that is in process.js if it finds that the request content-type is application/xml, instead of having to constantly maintain the same code changes in both files?

My apologies that this explanation is kind of awkward.

Thanks,
Jim

Comment: Factor out the common code into it's own module that you can then call from two different places.  Or make one function that takes parameters that determine what it should do so you can have just one function in one place that you use in two places.  This has nothing to do with node.js or express, it's just normal programming design and factoring.

Comment: Hi, Ok, thanks.  I know I can do that but was hoping that there was something in the way the the routes work that I might be able to leverage.

Comment: Routes are just normal code.  I don't follow exactly what you're trying to do, but you could use middleware that sees every request and then have a given middleware examine the request and see if it should do its thing or not.  And middleware can leave state on the `req` object for future route handlers if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the URL from the use parameter and every route will be hit by your function. You can then have base or common logic applied to all and reserve the dedicated routes for more specific processing reserved for a specific route. For example:

```
app.use(sharedRouteLogic) //executed on all routes
app.use('/arest/xml', xmlSpecificRoute);
app.use('/api/process', processSpecificRoute);
```

**Post Processing Headers or Caching**

The same logic applies to responses. You can configure callbacks that are applied to all of your responses.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Cache-Control', 'private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
  res.header('Expires', '-1');
  res.header('Pragma', 'no-cache');
  next();
})
```